# Why is my image in the centre of my page despite having used `vertical-align: top;`

Tags: html, css

I have an image for my static webpage, and that image uses a `vertical-align: top;` CSS property. But the image is still in the centre of my page.
Here is HTML:

```css
.login-page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.phone {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(0.65);
}

.ig-logo {
  transform: scale(0.35);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-page">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1" alt="phone" class="phone">

  <div class="login">
    <div class="login-box">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=2" class="ig-logo" alt="logo">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was expecting my code to put the image at the top of my page. I have tried `display: inline-block;`. But nothing is working.

Comment: because the scale transform use the image center at scale(1) for reference has default.

Comment: Add `transform-origin: top;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transform-origin: top;`

By default, the origin of a transform is `center`. <sup>[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)</sup>

```css
.login-page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.phone {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(0.65);
  transform-origin: top;
}

.ig-logo {
  transform: scale(0.35);
  display: inline-block;
  transform-origin: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-page">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1" alt="phone" class="phone">

  <div class="login">
    <div class="login-box">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=2" class="ig-logo" alt="logo">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```